# Blank screen on Magento install

Tags: php, magento, installation

I just installed a new version of Magento CE (1.8) on BlueHost, and I'm getting super inconsistent results.  After FTPing all the files into a directory called "magento", and trying to run the magento/install.php script I'm getting a totally blank screen.

I tried running magento-check.php and got the message "Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento."

I  checked PHP errors on my server and there are none.

---

Tried to install Magento files on another server space, also on Bluehost (downloaded them fresh from Magento website).  This time I could get through the eneitre installation process, but when I try and access the GUI front end or back end I get the white screen of death again.

This time with a PHP error:

[27-Nov-2013 19:07:45] PHP Fatal error:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /tmp) in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 125

Thanks for any and all help!!

Comment: Sounds like a question for your hosting support.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  It turned out to be an integral error with the hosting server and the 1.8 CE release.  I installed a clean version of Magento through the "Mojo Marketplace" which has the 1.7.1 release and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Delete this file app\etc\local.xml and try to install again.May be helpful!